Problem with kSOAP2 connection with TLSv1.2 webservice
We are having problems with a connection to a webservice with ksoap2 in android java:
The webservice is hosted on an https server with a TLSv1.2 connection that we can access with a VPN.
There is correct access to the server and there are no connection problems.
If I try to consume the webservice in SOAPUI it works with a timeout when getting a response, but if I change the SOAPUI property called Skip SOAPAction to true, it works perfectly.
The problem comes when I try to replicate this in ksoap2 and I can't get it to work, since it always gives a timeout.
We have the same webservice hosted on other servers with other VPNs and they work perfectly with ksoap2.
This with a HttpsURLConnection connection works perfectly but to deal with the response, it becomes much more problematic than ksoap2 and with longer times when processing responses:
This is the valid code with HttpsURLConnection:
URL obj = new URL(url);
SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
ssl.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(ssl.getSocketFactory());
connection.setConnectTimeout(30000); 
connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(Constants.REQUEST);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
Integer responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); // 200

With ksoap, we have tried many approaches like the following, but always getting timeout:
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
     request.addProperty(SOAP_PROPERTY,soapRequest);
} else {
     PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
     propertyInfo.setName(SOAP_PROPERTY);
     propertyInfo.setValue(soapRequest);
     request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
}
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
// sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[0]; }
}}, new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE("HOST", port, service, 60000);
((HttpsServiceConnectionSE) transport.getServiceConnection()).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
// also tried with SOAP_ACTION with empty value but same result with timeout

thank you so much in advance!
